# Dynamic Programming Exercise

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming

I have been struggling through a dynamic programming exercise and I can't seem to get the hold of it. I'll write here the problem and also it's solution stating explicitly what I don't understand.

We are given 2 sequences `u1,u2,...,un` and `d1,d2,...,dm` and a matrix of dimensions `n x m` built of positive integers `C=[cij]`. A list of k pairs
 `((ui1, dj1),(ui2,dj2),...,(uik,djk))` is said to be non-intersecting if 
`i1 < 12 <..< ik` and `j1 < j2 <...< jk`.
The "compatibility of a list" is said to be the compatibility of the sum of the pairs that it is made of, that is `Ci1j1 + Ci2j2 + ... + Cikjk`

Example :
Consider the matrix `C = [Cij]`, so `Cij = squared(i + j)`. Let i be
`i = 1, 2, 3,  j = 1, 2, 3, 4` and `k = 2`. Some lists of 2 non-intersecting pairs are these `((u1, d2),(u3, d3))` with a compatibility of  `9 + 36 = 45`,
`((u2, d2),(u3, d4))`, with compatibility `16 + 49 = 65,` and `((u1, d1),(u2, d4)),` with compatibility of `4 + 36 = 40`. Some lists that are not non-intersecting are the following : `((u2, d2),(u3, d1)),((u1, d4),(u3, d3)),((u3, d2),(u2, d3))`

Solution:

M(i, j, t) = maximum cost of t non-intersecting pairs taken from ui,...,un and dj,...dm

Recurrence equation :
`M(i, j, t) = max {M(i + 1, j + 1, t − 1) + c(i, j), M(i, j + 1, t),M(i + 1, j, t).}`

- `M(i, j, 0) = 0`
- `M(i, j, t) = −∞, if t > min{n − i + 1, m − j + 1}`
- `M(i, j, t) = 0, if i > n or j > m`

I don't under the reccurrence very well and why do we assign `−∞` to `M(i, j, t)` when  `t > min{n − i + 1, m − j + 1}` but 0 when `i > n` or `j > m`

The solution is M(1, 1, k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
M(i, j, t) = max {M(i + 1, j + 1, t − 1) + c(i, j), M(i, j + 1, t),M(i + 1, j, t).}
           = max
             {
                 M(i+1, j+1, t-1) + c(i, j), <- we know the maximum cost of t-1 
                                                non-intersecting pairs taken from
                                                i+1,...,n and j+1,...,m to which
                                                we prepend the pair (i, j).
                 M(i, j+1, t), <- keep it at t elements and don't prepend anything,
                                  and take the one containing elements from
                                  i,...,n and j+1,...,m
                 M(i+1, j, t) <- same, but take elements from i+1,...,n and j,...,m
             }
```

This covers all cases: either we prepend the current element and increase the length by 1 or we don't increase the length and take the maximum of the possibilities this (lack of) action entails. You might ask "but what about `M(i+1,j+1,t)`? that's also a valid possibility." It is, but it's covered by the two other cases: `M(i+1,j,t)` will check `M(i+1,j+1,t)` and return it if needed. You could add it yourself to the recurrence, it wouldn't be wrong, just redundant.

> why do we assign −∞ to M(i, j, t) when  t > min{n − i + 1, m − j + 1}

Because you cannot have a solution in that case. At step `i`, you can only pick `n - i + 1` elements from the first sequence (because you already picked up to `i`). Same for `j`. If `t > min{n - i + 1, m - j + 1}`, then you will not be able to pick the needed number of elements from one of the lists, and you mark that with negative infinity.

> but 0 when i > n or j > m

This is just to handle out of range errors. I'm not sure why they choose `0`, I would choose negative infinity for this as well just for consistency, or just avoid it altogether by putting conditions in the implementation (if `i + 1 >= n` then ignore this branch, although you'll still need to return 0/-infinity if none of the branches are valid), but it doesn't really matter.

If you return `0` and the answer is negative, then you'll run into problems. Of course, for your problem, due to the way `C` is built, we cannot have a negative solution (because C contains squares of numbers, which are `>= 0` always). So you could go with `0` instead of negative infinity in the first case as well.

**Exercise:** can you write a similar recurrence, but for which the solution is given by `M(n, m, k)`? Define it in words first, and then mathematically.